# jQuery facebook FB.Event.subscribe not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am developing a Facebook canvas app.

Trying to login and authorize my app is working fine.

**But this scenario doesn't work**.

1. I open my application canvas   https://apps.facebook.com/`{appID}`
2. Click on `Continue as` button.
3. Popup will show and I click on `Continue As`... to authorize.
4. Every thing looks fine and it's redirecting to main.php
5. I go to `app settings` and remove my app. **Update:** Also logoff all facebook; same result!
6. Here I am expecting `main.php` to alert me that the user removed app (deauthorized) then logoff
7. Nothing happen and user still in the page

**Here is my code**:

```
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js,
    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id))
        return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
    (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '{APPID}',
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access
        // the session
        xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
        version: 'v2.10', // use graph api version 2.8
        status: true,
        oAuth: true

    });

    //start coding
    // here trying all types of events subscribe to check if something
    // missing or if I am subscribing the wrong event
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
        alert("authResponseChange=" + response);
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        alert("login=" + response);
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
        alert("statusChange=" + response);
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        alert("getLoginStatus=" + response);
    });

};

function ReadPHPresponse(data, cmd) {
    //TODO
}

// end coding
```

**App environments**:

1. App in development mode
2. Its running on localhost WAMP
3. Tried everything I could to disable caching: WAMP, FB Calls, `stats:true`
4. In App setting I select the `canvas URL` to `https://localhost/` and app domain to `localhost`
5. In Facebook Login Products setting also I checked Valid OAuth redirect URIs
   to `https://localhost/`
6. FB API version 2.10

Still not firing and users not logged off when they remove my app.
If I refresh `main.php` its working and users get logged off.

I saw the following similar questions/answer but none of them solve my issue.

[why facebook FB.Event.subscribe is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13467139/7735285)

[how to detect log out from fb using JS SDK without refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24968034/7735285)

[FB JS-SDK cannot detect user logging out of FB directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7857421/7735285)

[How to detect user logging out of Facebook after logging into my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16227872/7735285)

I wonder whats wrong.

Thank you

**Update:** the event is fired but after waiting like an hour; so most likely its some caching issue! Can't be sure.

**Update2:**

Trying to figure out whats wrong! I had tried the following:

1. Downgrade `jQuery` from version 3 to version 2
2. Load my app from Live Server and not `localhost`
3. Check `app settings`
4. Check `console.log` for everything; but no error is returned! with All Levels enabled; I am getting only `[Violation] 'message' handler took 2450ms`
5. Checked Facebook Platform and it is `Healthy`
6. Loaded Facebook SDK into `<head>` (`sdk.js`)
7. Tried different browsers Chrome Latest, FF Latest and Edge Latest and Mobile same result. Only Edge return : `The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.` Which I think irrelevant.
8. Also tried to use FB API V 2.8

***Still no joy***

Here is my app settings:

[image: App settings]

[image: Deauthorize call back setting]

That's so funny! Please advice!

Thank you

Comment: What's the actual use case that would require it that this works instantly? Users removing the app while looking at its canvas version is probably not an everyday thing.

Comment: Being in local host; when a user deauthorize an app; dosn't make sense to consider that they logged out. Also when they logout from facebook they stay in the app...in development mode I want to see they are out of my app; because I am developing in local host not directly in the canvas...anyway why you think the subscribe.event dosn't fire. On local host it take an hour then it fires! Even in the canvas; it take also an hour if I deauthorize from another page.

Comment: How does that answer my question, what you actually _need_ this for in the first place? If things go wrong during API calls due to missing permissions or an invalidated access token, the response will tell you. So, the matter of why this does not seem to behave as accurate or timely as you'd like aside - explain where/how that causes an _actual_ problem, please. (And just because you develop on localhost does not mean you can not test it inside the canvas iframe, btw.)

Comment: 1-I load the app on canvas. 2-Open new page and go to app setting. 3- deauthorize app. 4-go back to canvas. 5-I can still use the app. is this normal. I am trying to logoff as soon as user deauthorize my app. Same happen when I logout Facebook, it doesn't logout my app....they can go to URL directly and keep using it....(outside canvas)

Comment: Even tried different ISP; it works but takes like an hour! I guess need to report a bug to FB; hope I am wrong somewhere!